# Using str.contains on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, string, excel, pandas

This pandas python code generates the error message,

> "TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'"

I have no idea why because I'm trying to manipulate a str object

```
df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons[~df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons['V'].str.contains("File*|registry*")] #sorts, leaving only cases where reason is NOT File or Registry
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Can you post what happens with `df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons['V'].str.contains("File*|registry*")`, also do you need the asterisks here?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce. Can you post `df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons.to_msgpack()` for us?

Comment: @MikeGraham: are you sure about that?  `regex=True` is the default for `str.contains` in 0.16.2, anyway, and it seems to have used a regex compile for years.

Comment: Yeah the asterisks are just there to make it treat File and Registry as substrings

Comment: Ok EdChum - when I used your code I got:  raise ValueError('cannot index with vector containing '
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: Ok Mike Graham - when I substitute in your code I get the same error - raise ValueError('cannot index with vector containing '
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: Could it be something as simple as I have Nan values in my df?

Comment: Ok it was that. Sorry, I'm very new - I've been doing this a month and I've launched into pandas with no background even in python - so I need a lot of  help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Credit to Davtho1983 comment above, I thought I'd add color to the comment for clarity.

For anyone stumbling on this later with the same error (like me).
It's a very simple fix. The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) from pandas shows

```
Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True)
```

What's happening is the contains() method isn't being applied to na values in the DataFrame, they will remain na. You just need to fill na values with Boolean values so you may use the invert operator `~` .

With the example above one should use

```
df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons[~df_Anomalous_Vendor_Reasons['V'].str.contains("File*|registry*", na=False)]
```

Of course one should choose False or True for the na argument based on intended logic. Whichever Boolean value you choose for filling na will be inverted.

Comment: goooood answer - i was quite confused by this

Comment: Tremendous Answer